# Keep getting type error in awk command in Python

Tags: python, bash, csv, awk, jq

Trying to turn a bash script into python using a subprocess but its not working. keep getting type errors on the jq command

```
filename = temp.csv
with open (filename, 'a') as file_name: 
  ndfile="account.csv" 
  with open(ndfile, 'a')
    for line in ndfile: 
      line = line.strip()
      result = subprocess.run(["jq -r '.accountdata[] | [id, name, number, date] | @csv'"], stdout=open(file_name, 'a'))
      result.write(line)
   subprocess.run(['awk', '-F', ',', '!seen[$1]++', file_name], stdout=open(ndfile, 'w'))
```

Comment: Answers would profit from disclosing some input data and the error message. Therefore just guessing: Did you mean `.accountdata[] | [.id, .name, .number, .date] | @csv` (dots before column/field names)?

Comment: `filename = temp.csv` is missing quotes around the filename.

Comment: `for line in ndfile:` is looping over the characters in the filename, not the contents of the file. You also opened both files in `a` mode, shouldn't you be reading from one of them? And you're missing `as variable` in the second `with`.

Comment: Why are you running `jq` and `awk` from Python? Python has its own JSON library, and you can easily get unique values in Python instead of running `awk`.

Comment: It appears you mean to *read* from `ndfile`; it should be opened with `'r'`, not `'a'`, as its mode.

Comment: Does the original file, temp.csv, have multiple rows of JSON?

Answer (score 0):

```
subprocess.run(["jq -r '.accountdata[] | [id, name, number, date] | @csv'"])
```

Runs a single binary with the name `jq -r '.accountdata[] | [id, name, number, date] | @csv'` without any parameters – but the name of your binary is `jq` and you want to run it with 2 parameters!

```
subprocess.run(["jq", "-r", "'.accountdata[] | [id, name, number, date] | @csv'"])
```

Will run the binary with 2 parameters. Alternatively, pass a single string instead of the array and specify `shell=True`:

```
subprocess.run("jq -r '.accountdata[] | [id, name, number, date] | @csv'", shell=True)
```

Same goes for your `awk` call. But even better: use python directly, it can already manipulate JSON and line-based data just fine.